# Is using a width less than zero portable behaviour in SDL2

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

I am making use of what looks like a bit of a cheat of SDL2's SDL_Rect struct. In my program I wanted a rectangle to "grow" from the right to the left side of the screen. To do this I tried to decrement the width attribute of the rect below zero and, in fact, it has the correct effect. However, I am left with the question of is this correct, portable behaviour. I understand that in the real world it does not make sense to have a rectangle with a negative width. However, it seems that the SDL developers may have intended for this to be the case. In SDL1.2 the SDL_Rect structure was defined as using an unsigned integer to [represent the width and height](https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlrect.html) whereas in SDL2 the SDL_Rect [uses signed integers](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Rect). Included below is code that exhibits this "cheat", error checking omitted for brevity.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#define SCREEN_W 640
#define SCREEN_H 480

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)
    
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("test", 110, 110, SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H, 0);
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    
    SDL_Rect rects[5];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        rects[i].w = 0;
        rects[i].h = (SCREEN_H / 5);
        rects[i].x = (i % 2) * SCREEN_W;
        rects[i].y = i * (SCREEN_H / 5);
    }
    
    SDL_Event e;
    bool running = true;
    
    while(running)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                running = false;
            }
        }
        
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rects[i]);
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                rects[i].w++;
            }
            else
            {
                rects[i].w--;
            }
        }
        
        if (rects[0].w == SCREEN_W)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                rects[i].w = 0;
            }
        }
        
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
    
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    
    SDL_Quit();
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I will reiterate, I do not think this invokes any undefined behaviour but I am unsure if this is portable behaviour within the context of SDL2. Should I expect my code to work on everyone's machine today and going forward?

Comment: SDL will clip it to visible area, however integer could eventually overflow if you go way too far.